# Regular expressions in python specific string plus numeric

Tags: python, regex

I want to get from f all the 11 characters that will always start with
AL0 plus 8 digits. I tried the following but is not working properly

```
import re

p=r"AL0\d{8}"

f= "take this one AL012345678 , not this one fAL012345670 , nor AL0123333333311, nor AL012345679f ,but also AL012345555."

m=re.findall(p,f)

print (m)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "is not working properly". What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: When using code in a question, please put all code into code blocks: usually, indent all code lines by 4 spaces, or surround the code block with 3 backticks (`\`\`\``). For inline code on the same line as non-code, surround the code with a single backtick on each side (`\``).

Comment: I want the output to be [‘AL012345678’,’AL012345555’]

Comment: Use word boundaries, see https://ideone.com/uSSwdJ